# How to install correctly Laravel 5.2 on a shared / reseller hosting (hostgator)?

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I have a fresh installation of Laravel 5.2.43 via ssh with composer on a reseller hosting account from Hostgator. Laravel is installed in the root like this:

```
 /home/user/laravel
```

I want to do the following: to move the public folder from Laravel internal structure, this is the url:

```
/home/user/laravel/public
```

to another folder inside the public_html, this would be the url:

```
/home/user/public_html/laravel-public-folder-here
```

How can I do that using the right way?

To make the redirect I wanted to use the last steps from this forum post:

http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-how-to-install-laravel-on-a-hostgator-shared-server

But it seems that Laravel 5.2 doesn't have the file "laravel/bootstrap/paths.php". Probably the forum post is for an older version of Laravel.

Please answer if you know how I can do that in the right way. I have looked on answers on similar questions here on stack, but they didn't solve my issue, Probably is just a Laravel config matter which I miss at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to ask hostGator support about that.
Laravel is a composer project. So, you need to be sure if the composer is installed on your host. I remember HostGator does not allow to install the composer (refer to 4 month ago). Ask them

Comment: Composer is installed on the server by me via ssh. I installed Laravel using composer.

Answer (score 0):

You only needs copy all your files of laravel project and put in folder **/public_html**, the next step is create an **.htaccess** file in **/public_html** with this code:

```
## Redirect to public folder
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
        RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

this work's for me in godaddy.

Regards!

Comment: From what you say it means that I will have to install the project inside the /public_html folder and not outside of it one folder up as I did. I will give it a try as you said and see if it works properly. Thanks for the answer for now, if it works properly I will accept your answer, if not I will come with comments.

Comment: Yes you will to install all your proyect inside public_html, and create the file .htaccess in the root of public_html.

Comment: I have created a new Laravel project inside the /public_html folder and inside the project root I added the .htaccess file in order to point to /public. But unfortunately when I access the project root /project/ I get a Laravel error saying: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." and "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:" followed by more details. When I access project/public it works well.

Comment: I managed to do a redirect with a symbolic link. Like this: ln -s /home/user/laravel-project/public/index.php /home/user/public_html/symlink-folder   For now it works well on a fresh installation. It is recommended that you should have the Laravel files outside /public folder for security reasons. With the symbolic link this is solved as Laravel is installed outside public_html. Anyhow thanks Radames for your help!

Comment: the code I put in my answer is to redirect you to the public folder, and the reason that I place all files within the folder it is because I have multiple installations laravel on my server